# Simple solidity code not returning any value with remix ide

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract practice {

   int a = 10;

   function trial() public returns (int) {
       return a;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions can either be invoked via *transactions* or *calls*. Transactions are used for functions that mutate state, and transactions do not have return values. Calls cannot mutate state but do have return values.

Remix uses a call only when the function has the `pure` or `view` modifier. Just add `view`, and things will work how you expect:

```
function trial() public view returns (uint) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function definition to include `view`. Then it will return the value of `a` in Remix IDE.

```
function trial() public view returns (int) {
    return a;
}
```